# Why is PHP File Adding SQL Records Twice

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have the following code, where the user inputs information to a table, then when clicking an "upload" button, the following JS function is called, where an AJAX request is sent to the PHP file to insert the user entered data into a SQLite3 database. For some reason, everytime I submit, the SQLite DB has 2 duplicate records for each row of the input table. It seems like either the JS function or PHP file is adding each table row twice, although I'm not able to pinpoint where it is occurring. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```js
        function uploadTable(){
            var data = document.getElementsByClassName("manUploadRow");
            resp = "";
            for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var term=data[i].children[0].children[0].value;
                var cid=data[i].children[1].children[0].value;
                var cname=data[i].children[2].children[0].value;
                var prof=data[i].children[3].children[0].value;
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "manUpload.php?term="+term+"&cCode="+cid+"&cName="+cname+"&prof="+prof, false);
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        resp = resp + this.responseText;
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = resp;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

```css
<?php
require_once "functions.php";
$term = $_GET["term"];
$cCode =  $_GET["cCode"];
$cName =  $_GET["cName"];
$prof =  $_GET["prof"];

$db = new SQLite3("../database/database.db");
$query = "insert into course (coursecode, coursename, prof, term) values ( '$cCode', '$cName', '$prof', '$term');";
echo $query;
if($db->exec($query)){
    echo "Successfully Registered";
}
else {
    echo "Failed to enter into database, see the following error code: ";
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
}
$db->close();
unset($db);
?>
```

```html
                            <tr id="templateRow-1" class="manUploadRow">
                                <td><input type="text" id="row-1-term" name="row-1-term" placeholder="Term with Month and Year"></td>
                                <td><input type="number" id="row-1-num" name="row-1-num" placeholder="Course Number"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="row-1-name" name="row-1-name" placeholder="Course Name"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="row-1-instructor" name="row-1-instructor" placeholder="Instructor"></td>
                            </tr>
                    <tr id="templateRow-2" class="manUploadRow">
                                <td><input type="text" id="row-2-term" name="row-2-term" placeholder="Term with Month and Year"></td>
                                <td><input type="number" id="row-2-num" name="row-2-num" placeholder="Course Number"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="row-2-name" name="row-2-name" placeholder="Course Name"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="row-2-instructor" name="row-2-instructor" placeholder="Instructor"></td>
                            </tr></tbody>
```

Comment: How and when is `uploadTable` called? (also note that your code is wide open to sql injection)

Comment: Can you show the HTML and the event handler that calls uploadTable?

Comment: Judging by the php you provided, there is no looping there. So our best bet is the JS is firing off twice. Be sure to debug JS using your developer tools in the web browser (note the Network tab and how many xhr calls it makes when you click a button).

Comment: I dont have an event handler, rather a button where onclick calls the JS function ive put above. Also, i've debugged the JS script and it loops the correct amount of times. I thought it might be weird behaviour  from the AJAX call.

Comment: Just checked and there are two xhr calls for every time the js function is called. Still cant figure out why it is being called twice.